Best way to show dynamic changes on Image in Gridview with MVVM
I would like to show several Images in an Gridview and show on this picture some circles like an overlay.For Example show several rooms and do circles in different places for lamps or outlets and change color, if the state changed. I made an prototype with an big canvas, uses several images and then place this "dots" with coordinates.
Now i created an model with an string for the path of the image and a List with items (own class with x,y,color) for several dots. I created an itemcontrol with an canvas, set the picture as Background an now i would like to make circles or dots for every point in this list.
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Intersections}" FontFamily="Bahnschrift" Margin="10,10,10,10" AutomationProperties.IsRowHeader="False" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Background="#A5FFFFFF" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinHeight="500"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="200" Height="200" >
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding MapPath}" />
                </Canvas.Background>                    
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

internal class Intersection
{
    private String _mapPath;
    public String MapPath
    {
        get
        {
            return _mapPath;
        }
        set
        {
            _mapPath = value;
        }
    }
    public String Name;
    public List<Signals> Signals;

    public Intersection(String name, String mapPath)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.MapPath = mapPath;
        Signals = new List<Signals>();
    }

    public void AddSignal(Signals signals)
    {
        Signals.Add(signals);
    }

}

internal class Signals
{
    public int SignalX = 0;
    public int SignalY = 0;
    public Color ColorOn = Color.Green;
    public Color ColorOff = Color.Red;

    public Signals(int x, int y)
    {
        SignalX = x;
        SignalY = y;
    }
}

How can i draw the dots on every picture and how am i able to update this? Or is there an better way to do this?
Here is an example from my prototyp.
enter image description here
Later the user should be able to change row and columns to fit this layout to their screen.
Edit: Here do I insert testdata
 private ObservableCollection<Intersection> _intersections;
    public IEnumerable<Intersection> Intersections => 
    _intersections;


    public HomeViewModel(DataStore dataStore)
    {
    this.dataStore = dataStore;
    _intersections = new ObservableCollection<Intersection>();
    Intersection test1 = new Intersection("test1", 
    "/test/testknoten107.png");
    Intersection test2 = new Intersection("test2", 
    "/test/testknoten108.png");
    
    test1.AddSignal(new Signals(400, 400));
    test1.AddSignal(new Signals(100, 100));
    test1.AddSignal(new Signals(2000, 2000));
    test1.AddSignal(new Signals(300, 300));
    
    test2.AddSignal(new Signals(100, 100));
    test2.AddSignal(new Signals(100, 200));
    test2.AddSignal(new Signals(200, 100));
    test2.AddSignal(new Signals(200, 200));
    _intersections.Add(test1);
    _intersections.Add(test2);
    }

With the solution from Tarazed I got the most of the behaviour I want. Now the only problem is, that the dots, they supposed to be over the map, are in the top-left corner.
Red Dot stuck in corner
EDIT 2:
Changed the set of the Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left to an ItemContainerStyle Layer. Now it works
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Intersections}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
        <Border Width="620" Margin="10,10,10,10" Padding="5" >
            <Image Width="600" Height="600" Source="{Binding MapPath}" />
        </Border>       
            
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SignalList}" >                            
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="20" Height="20"/>                                
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding SignalX}" />
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding SignalY}" />
                </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Height="600" Width="600"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
            
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>


Load (smart) UserControls; not (simple) templated items. A wonderful anti-MVVM pattern that can do anything you want.

Since you have a collection inside elements of another collection, you will have to nest a Signals ItemsControl inside the DataTemplate of the Intersections ItemsControl.  If you use a Grid with no columns or rows, you can stack the new ItemsControl on top of the background image (which might no longer need a canvas, you could probably just use an Image).
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Intersections}" FontFamily="Bahnschrift" Margin="10,10,10,10" AutomationProperties.IsRowHeader="False" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Background="#A5FFFFFF" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <UniformGrid Columns="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinHeight="500"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Image Source="{Binding MapPath}"/>
          
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Signals}" >
          <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <Ellipse Canvas.Left="{Binding SignalX}" Canvas.Top="{Binding SignalY}" Width="5" Height="5"/>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

As a side note, I also advise against using accessible fields.  Anything that can be a public field can be a property easily. Even if it's just an auto-property, it will save you a lot of trouble down the road.  Keep those fields private... always.
public int SignalX { get; }
public int SignalY { get; }
public Color ColorOn { get; } = Color.Green;
public Color ColorOff { get; } = Color.Red;

public string Name { get; }
public List<Signals> Signals { get; } = new();


Good solution, there is one Problem left. There is no error, but the "dots" were not draw. One dot is drawed at the coordinates 0,0, but no other dots.

It looks like the dots can not be placed freely inside this canvas. From another post I saw, the Person suggested to put the canvas outside of this second ItemsControl. When I do this, I got the amount of dots, but they are all ordered from top to button. If I hardcode some coordinate, they also in the same corner

@MattHias Are you sure your signals are added correctly?  You didn't post any of that code, so I can't tell from this where the ellipses would be placed.  Are you adding the signals before creating the view or after?  There is no indication of observable behavior here (INotifyPropertyChanged/ObservableCollections)

The ItemsPanel is created by the ItemsControl, there is no way to put it outside of the ItemsControl.

You can decorate the canvas though. As panels have a bad habit of being invisible, you can put a colored border around them in the Panel template so you can visualize their size.

When I turn the Backgroundcolor to an visible color I can see, that the canvas has the right size.

The only thing I can think of is changing the List to an ObservableCollection, but since you are initializing them in the constructor, I wouldn't expect that to be an issue.  Unfortunately, I'm just not seeing a reason they wouldn't lay out on the canvas coordinates.

I tried it but it has no affect
